# swiftui mask and allowsHitTesting conflicts

Tags: swiftui

I have a ZStack with two toggles -- front and back, when I set `allowsHitTesting` on the front, the back is triggered when I click, that's what I want.

but when I add `mask` modifier to the front, the thing changes, there is no reaction when I click it

The mask is used for animation, so it's necessary. Anything wrong with my code? thanks!

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var switchBack:Bool = false
    @State var switchFront:Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            ZStack{
                VStack{
                    Toggle("", isOn: $switchBack).labelsHidden()
                }
                
                VStack{
                    Toggle("", isOn: $switchFront).labelsHidden()
                }
                .allowsHitTesting(false)
//                .mask(
//                    Rectangle().frame(height:0))
            }
            Text("back:\(switchBack ? "on" : "off"),front:\(switchFront ? "on" : "off")")
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: How about moving `.allowsHitTesting` below `.mask`? As far as I know, View related modifier returns a modified view that isn't affected by any modifiers set previously.

Comment: @KyokookHwang I added the `.allowsHitTesting ` below `.mask`, above `.mask`, to the `Rectangle` in the `.mask`, nothing changed.

Comment: With "allowsHitTesting(false) and mask(...)" seems to work on ios 15 and macCatalyst 12.
     What system are you on?

Comment: @workingdog iOS14, where did you find the explanation?

Comment: I'm on macos 12, targeting ios 15 using xcode 13. Tested the code as is, with the "mask" line uncommented of course. Explanation ???

Comment: @workingdog I mean official explanation from Apple. So it seems a bug.